# Program won't load my custom DLL instead of Windows one

Tags: dll

I am trying to proxy WS2_32.dll but no matter what I do it always loads the systems one instead. I used a tool to check and it is loading the systems one:

```
0x00000000775c0000  0x67000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WS2_32.dll
```

I heard windows blocks this one from being loaded if its in the same directory. Is there anyway to override this?

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a security feature of Windows here. Known Windows DLL's are loaded from trusted locations (and secured against modification there). So no, there's no publicly known method. And if one would become known, you would expect a patch very shortly afterwards.

Comment: Is there any other way for me to proxy the functions so I can intercept packets and inject my own?

Comment: No and yes. No, you can't proxy the functions. Yes, you can intercept packets, but you do that at the filter driver level.